# NGRX state spread operator Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()'

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am using NGRX Entity adapter to initialize state (problem occurs only with `getInitialState`).

```
 export const initialState = adapter.getInitialState({
      eventsError: null,
      eventsLoading: false
    });

    export function reducer(
      state = initialState,
      action: EventsActions
    ): State {
      switch (action.type) {

        case EventsActionTypes.getAllEvents: {
          return Object.assign({}, ...state, { // error line
            eventsLoading: true
          });
        }
// ...
```

When i want to use spread operator on state object I get an error:

```
ERROR in src/app/events/reducers/events.reducer.ts(36,35): error TS2488: Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

Here is my tsconfig.json file

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `Object.assign` you don't use the spread operator:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, { eventsLoading: true });
```

Which is equivalent to using object spread like this:

```
return { ...state, eventsLoading: true }
```

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) merges multiple *objects*, where as [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) expands the keys of an object *into an object literal*. For the most part object spread makes `Object.assign` obsolete.